# How do I change the input attributes of a text field using GreaseMonkey/TamperMonkey?

Tags: google-chrome, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

**How do I remove the readonly attribute from this input field?**

```
<input class=" calendar_field" id="zoom_meeting_room[scheduled_on]" name="zoom_meeting_room[scheduled_on]" readonly="readonly" type="text" value="2020-11-07 12:08">
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example:

```js
document.querySelector('#zoom_meeting_room[scheduled_on]').removeAttribute('readonly');
```

or

```js
document.getElementById('zoom_meeting_room[scheduled_on]').removeAttribute('readonly');
```

In order to avoid errors

```js
const input = document.getElementById('zoom_meeting_room[scheduled_on]');
if (input) { input.removeAttribute('readonly'); }
```

or

```js
const input = document.getElementById('zoom_meeting_room[scheduled_on]');
input && input.removeAttribute('readonly');
```

You can also set it to `false`

```js
const input = document.getElementById('zoom_meeting_room[scheduled_on]');
if (input) { input.readOnly = false; }
```

or

```js
const input = document.getElementById('zoom_meeting_room[scheduled_on]');
if (input) { input.setAttribute('readonly', false); }
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked using the executescript in Selenium IDE.

Comment: How do I remove the visibility and position from this: `<input class=" calendar_field" id="zoom_meeting_room[scheduled_on]" name="zoom_meeting_room[scheduled_on]" type="text" value="2020-11-07 18:44">`

Comment: @user14595209 What do you mean? changing style?

Comment: Hi again, the input field has a css style (visibility and position that hides it). Initially I wanted to turn those css atrributes off. But I managed to remove the whole class from the input using `document.getElementById("zoom_meeting_room[scheduled_on]").className =
  document.getElementById("zoom_meeting_room[scheduled_on]").className
    .replace(new RegExp('(?:^|\\s)'+ 'calendar_field' + '(?:\\s|$)'), ' ');`

Comment: @user14595209 You can change the visibility directly e.g. `input.style.visibility = 'visible'; `. If you explain clearly in the original question or in a new question, then a proper reply will be added. It is difficult to discus it in the comment section.